# Shortest way to initialize an array out of two arrays?

Tags: rust

What's the shortest way to build an array in Rust as follows:

```
let byte: u8 = 1;
let foo: u32 = 5;
// How do I do this?
let out: [u8; 5] = byte + foo.to_be_bytes();
```

In other words, I want to concatenate a single byte and 4 bytes together to form a 5 byte array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first thing that comes to mind:

```
fn main() {
    let byte: u8 = 1;
    let foo: u32 = 5;

    let mut out: [u8; 5] = [0; 5];
    out[..1].copy_from_slice(&[byte]); // Copy the byte to the first element
    out[1..].copy_from_slice(&foo.to_be_bytes()); // Copy the bytes of foo to the remaining elements

    println!("{:?}", out);
}
```

Or maybe using one-liner. Don't really know if it's more intuitive than first try:

```
let out: [u8; 5] = [byte].iter()
                         .chain(&foo.to_be_bytes())
                         .copied()
                         .collect::<Vec<_>>()
                         .try_into()
                         .unwrap();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just for the purpose of playing with this example, here is a solution trying to initialise directly the array from an iterator, without storing into an intermediate vector.
Note that I *largely prefer* the `.copy_from_slice()` from another answer (upvote it); I used it here just to show the generated code, and it looks better.

```rust
#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
fn five_bytes(
    byte: u8,
    foo: u32,
) -> [u8; 5] {
    let mut bytes_iter = [byte].into_iter().chain(foo.to_be_bytes());
    [std::mem::MaybeUninit::<u8>::uninit(); 5]
        .map(|_b| bytes_iter.next().unwrap())
}

#[no_mangle]
#[inline(never)]
fn five_bytes_copy(
    byte: u8,
    foo: u32,
) -> [u8; 5] {
    let mut out = [0_u8; 5];
    out[..1].copy_from_slice(&[byte]);
    out[1..].copy_from_slice(&foo.to_be_bytes());
    out
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", five_bytes(1, 5));
    println!("{:?}", five_bytes_copy(1, 5));
}
/*
[1, 0, 0, 0, 5]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 5]

$ objdump --disassemble=five_bytes target/release/my_project
...
0000000000006ae0 <five_bytes>:
    6ae0:   0f ce                   bswap  %esi
    6ae2:   89 f1                   mov    %esi,%ecx
    6ae4:   c1 e9 18                shr    $0x18,%ecx
    6ae7:   48 c1 e1 20             shl    $0x20,%rcx
    6aeb:   c1 e6 08                shl    $0x8,%esi
    6aee:   40 0f b6 c7             movzbl %dil,%eax
    6af2:   09 f0                   or     %esi,%eax
    6af4:   48 09 c8                or     %rcx,%rax
    6af7:   c3                      ret
...

$ objdump --disassemble=five_bytes_copy target/release/my_project
...
0000000000006b00 <five_bytes_copy>:
    6b00:   0f ce                   bswap  %esi
    6b02:   48 c1 e6 08             shl    $0x8,%rsi
    6b06:   40 0f b6 c7             movzbl %dil,%eax
    6b0a:   48 09 f0                or     %rsi,%rax
    6b0d:   c3                      ret
...
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the comparisons. I chose the latter also after playing around in the compiler explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [concat-arrays](https://crates.io/crates/concat-arrays).

```rust
use concat_arrays::concat_arrays;

fn main() {
    let byte: u8 = 1;
    let foo: u32 = 5;
    let out: [u8; 5] = concat_arrays!(byte.to_be_bytes(), foo.to_be_bytes());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `to_be_bytes()` for big endian or `to_le_bytes()` for little endian:

```
let byte: u8 = 1;
let foo: u32 = 5;
let one: [u8; 1] = [byte];
let four: [u8; 4] = u32::to_be_bytes(foo);
let out: [u8; 5] = [&one, &four[..]].concat().try_into().unwrap();
```